# How do I open a file .sh ( shell ) from sketchware

Tags: javascript, java, android

Hello I am trying to create an Android application via a sketchware program but I am trying to find a command to run a file shell script from this path */storage/emulated/0/Download/on.sh*

I have code to run a package, but I can't change it !!!?

```
if (i == null) { return; }
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

I want such code to run from this path : */storage/emulated/0/Download/on.sh*

Comment: From the looks of it sketchware seems to be some kind of scratch-ish IDE for Android development on phones themselves. I can imagine that it does not support editing generated code blocks directly. Also the question is why you want to execute a shell script in the first place - most things can be done natively in the app.

Comment: It is an application that creates Android programs ... I need this in order to open a file in shell script